# Signtool error "No certificates were found that met all the given criteria."

Tags: ssl, driver, signtool

I am trying to Authenticode Signing of Third-party CSPs by using signtool.exe. Getting error "**Signtool error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria.**" in cmd. I got .pfx file from geotrust CA is valid up to 18 Nov, 2016 and converted it to .cer file. Command detail below

C:>signtool.exe sign /ac geotrustca3.cer /sha1 ‎7641647be6103815d7ceeb81710543ae5c5c538d /t "http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll" /d  “MyCertificate”  wipfwamd64.cat

*Note: SHA thumbprint code taken from .cer file provided by Certificate Authority (CA)*

By following document https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn553410(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: From the document your are quoting, there's a link to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn170454%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. They give a procedure to identify the .cer you need (not a pfx!) and the code signing certificate thumbprint. I think you will need to import your .pfx in your personal store (ok since it has been emitted by Geotrust), and Windows will allow signing of the CSP because your certificate will have a second trust chain linking it to Windows codesigning authority.

Comment: Right #lansus i have already import .pfx to personal and private certificate store by using MMC. My certificate also visible in MMC store.

Comment: What about the rest of my answer ? I'm not quite sure about what you did when you mention _"I converted it to .cer file"_...